# Convert activity into a view

Tags: android, camera

In mainactivity i've sidebar. In that sidebar, need to place the content of secondactivity. Secondactivity extends ListActivity which contains data fetched from database.

**MainActivity:**

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
RelativeLayout mainContainer = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.MainContainer);  
LayoutInflater layoutinflate = getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);   
View view = layoutinflate.inflate(R.layout.cameralist, null);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams                         (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
view.setLayoutParams(params);
mainContainer.addView(view);
```

**main.xml:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/MainContainer"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
</RelativeLayout>
```

**cameralist.xml:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/Sidebar"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#000000">

<TextView
      android:id="@+id/CameraHeading"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:text="  Camera List  "
      android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
      android:ellipsize="middle"/>

<com.fs.menuanimation.ViewCamera
      android:id="@+id/CamList"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

**SecondActivity:**

public class ViewCamera extends ListActivity {

```
String DB = AddCamera.DB_NAME;
String TABLE_NAME = AddCamera.TABLE_NAME;
ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
//SQLiteDatabase sampleDB = null;
SQLiteDatabase sampleDB = AddCamera.SMMSLITEDB;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    sampleDB =  this.openOrCreateDatabase(DB, MODE_PRIVATE, null);

    Cursor c = sampleDB.rawQuery("SELECT CameraName FROM " + TABLE_NAME , null);

    if (c != null ) {
        if  (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                String CameraName = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("CameraName"));
                //int age = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("Age"));
                results.add(CameraName);
            }while (c.moveToNext());
        } 
    }       
    this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,results));
}
```

}

Can anyone help me.

Comment: Sounds like a job for Fragments.

Comment: I'll be able to help you but I'm not getting which activity you want to convert. Please elaborate like what you are doing and what you want to do

Comment: I'm trying using fragments that why i didn't reply. I need to place SecondActivity(ViewCamera) into MainActivity.